# AWS S3 file upload integration with dropwizard?

Tags: java, file-upload, amazon-s3, jersey, dropwizard

I am new to **Dropwizard**. I want to implement **AWS S3 File upload** service in my project.

I am not getting any tutorial to upload file on AWS S3 through dropwizard.

I have added following dependecies in **pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.28.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have registered **MultiPartfeature.class** in **Application class's run()** method as -

```
environment.jersey().register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

Then in resource class defined method as -

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/updateProfilePicture")
public String updateProfile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) throws Exception {

    String url = "";
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials("MY-ACCESS-KEY", "MY-SECRET_KEY"));

try {
    File file = new File(contentDispositionHeader.getFileName());

    PutObjectResult putObjectResult = s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("BUCKET-NAME", s3SourceFactory.getSecretAccessKey(), fileInputStream, new ObjectMetadata()));

 } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
     ase.printStackTrace();
} catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
    ace.printStackTrace();
}
    return url;
}
```

But at run-time it shows the following log -

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client: No content length specified for stream data.  Stream contents will be buffered in memory and could result in out of memory errors.
```

How can I get the url of uploaded file? How to check file is uploaded through coding? Am I missing anything? Does anybody have any idea about this. If there any tutorial available with dropwizard, it will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the access key and secret key are correct. My guess is towards the S3 bucket permissions, once you go  to your s3 bucket on aws console, to the right top you will find "properties" , once you open that you will have permissions make sure you gave an entry for your server there.

Comment: Ok I will check it, one more thing how can I get the url of uploaded image?

Comment: select the file in the s3 bucket from the console and select properties to the right you should be able to see the link.